# Sailsjs Model.find() not retrieving foreign key

Tags: sails.js, associations, waterline

I have two models with a one-to-many association in sails v0.12: a Game model and a User model (one game has two users).

When I find a user, I would like to see its foreign key to the game object. I recall that I used to see this attribute in a previous version of sails, but it seems to have disappeared.

Here is a simplified version of my Models:

Game.js:

```
module.exports = { 

        name: {
                   type: 'string',
              },
        players: {
                   collection: 'user',
                   defaultsTo: []
                 }
    };
```

and User.js:

```
module.exports = {
    email: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
    game: {
        model: 'game'
    }
};
```

I would like to find a user model and see BOTH its 'email' and 'game' attributes. Here is a sample query:

```
User.find(7).exec(function gotUser(user) {
    console.log(user); // -> {'email': 'someUserEmail'} MISSING 'game'
}
```

**EDIT:**
The 'game' attribute does not appear even when calling populateAll() on the find():

```
User.find(7).populateAll().exec(function gotPopulatedUser(user) {
    console.log(user); // -> {'email': 'someUserEmail'} MISSING 'game'
}
```

Is there a way to see the ID of the game that the user is associated (the foreign key) with upon finding the user? Or do I *need* to search for all games that have user's ID in their players collection? What would be the syntax for that?

Comment: Call populate [DOCS](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries/populate) and see the magic...

Comment: I edited my post regarding populateAll(). I've tried populating from the User.find() call, and the resulting user record had neither the populated game, nor the foreign key to the game. I don't see any documentation about querying for the model with the collection based on the id's of the records in the collection. e.g. I would settle for being able to call Game.find({'players': {'contains': idOfMyUser}))
but I don't believe this is valid syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my mistake!

The model definition for the Game object was missing a 'via' key.

Somehow, the two had been associated adequately for populating game objects without this (game.find().populateAll() would successfully populate the 'players' attribute), but the Game model should read:

```
module.exports = {
    name: {
        type: 'string'
    },
    players: {
        collection: 'user',
        via: 'game', //This was missing
        defaultsTo: []
    }
};
```

With this line in place, User.find() will yield a user that has the ID of the associated game as its 'game' attribute, and user.find.populateAll() will yield a user that has the populated game as its 'game' object, as expected.